# Display one number in a column of repeating numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this problem I am not able to solve:

On the below table, I need to get the cash balance for every account

```
account cash balance

C        30,000.00

H        25,000.00

H        25,000.00

H        25,000.00

H        25,000.00 

H        25,000.00

H        25,000.00
```

so for account C, the formula could be:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"C",C:C)
```

But how about in getting balance for H account? I need to show 25,000 without deleting the duplicate amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

1. `AVERAGEIF`:

   `=AVERAGEIF(B:B,"H",C:C)`
2. `SUMIF` and `COUNTIF`:

   `=SUMIF(B:B,"H",C:C)/COUNTIF(B:B,"H")`
3. Finally: `Max` and `IF`

   `=MAX(IF(B:B,"H",C:C))`

please note that you need to use `ctrl+shift+enter` when you enter the last one.

Comment: I tried this one but it isnt working. Finally 3- Max and IF

=MAX(IF(B:B="H",1,0)*(C:C))

Comment: Please see the updated answer @pucktack. I tested it and I am sure that it should work. Let me know how it doesn't if it doesn't work with you.

Comment: hmh. think is what you are trying to say, =MAX(IF(B:B="H",C:C)) it worked on me

Comment: @pucktack yes this is what I referred to. Please mark the answer as an acceptable answer if it works for you.

Comment: Input with ctrl-shift-enter is needed because this is an **array function!** Very interesting concept!